# Model Login System: Implement Interface or Composition?

Tags: php, interface, domain-driven-design, composition

I'm developing a administrative application (in PHP), where the Administrator can register customers. There are 2 types of customers: Companies and Individuals. A Company 'has-many' ContactPersons, which can login to the application. A Individual can login 'himself'.

[image: Class diagram]

My question is, **what is the best way to model how the customers (and administrators) can login?**

- User / CanLogin / Authenticatable Interface, which ContactPerson and Individual will implement. This interface has a getUsername() and getPassword() method.
- User Class. Every ContactPerson and Individual 'has-many' User (composition).

[image: Interface or Composition]

> Note: a 'login-able' user (ContactPerson or Individual) can belong to
>   multiple customers. Even a ContactPerson can be the same person (same
>   username) as an Individual.

Thanks!

Comment: @Soundz Then I can't typehint a 'login-able' user. For example, a method AuthService::login(User $user) would then be impossible.

Comment: Typically you should aim to have an *Identity & Access Control* bounded context that is separate from your actual domain.  You are free to publish events that would result in a `SystemUser` being created but trying to place everything together may be problematic.

Comment: @EbenRoux that's a great advice and eye-opener! Will SystemUser in this case then have a reference (property) to ContactPerson or Individual?

Comment: No it would not.  Typically any AR that needs to "reference" another would only store the other ARs ID or a value object containing the ID and some basic denormalized value(s).  But an I&AC BC should not have any need for these things as other systems are actually somewhat downstream.  YMMV but you could possibly have the `SystemUserId` in the contact.  I would still try to see if that is at all necessary though.

Answer (score 0):

Have the Contactperson inherit the individual, and add a company id to the contactperson class

Comment: But when Individual has to inherit from a Person class, it cannot inherit the abstract class Customer anymore. Because you can only extend one  class in PHP.

Comment: Okey forget the Person class, you are right ;) but then you should be able to inherit all you want from Customer. For the login just add a login credential attribute (or multiple) there.

If you can't inherit the needed attributes from Customer because it would not be good for the company, then you should change your model. Make an interface out of Customer, and have two Classes, Company and Person implementing it, then your Individuals and your Contact Person can inherit Persons!

Comment: That's not possible either, because a Company itself cannot login, only its ContactPersons.

Comment: Yeah then you have to change the Customer Class into an interface. As far as i can see it here, it makes no sense for Company and individuals to extend the same class. They are to different. Or tell me what is in the Customer class.

Sorry for making such a mess with updating my comments ^ ^

Comment: In the Customer class there will be properties like Address, PhoneNumber, etc. But it could indeed also be an interface, but I thought Customers have more common implementation than Persons (Users). Thanks for your ideas so far :)

Comment: You could also make the Contact person inherit the individual, and have an attribute company. I think that's actually the cleanest solution for your problem (at least the cleanest i can think of right now ;))